# How can I turn into a great ape, fusion or evolve during the fight?

Tags: dragon-ball-z-budokai-tenkaichi-3

I saw a video on YouTube where every Dragon Ball character can do fusion in Budokai 3, but I cannot do it myself.

I've also read on Wikipedia that it is a way that Saiyans can turn into a great ape at night stages, but I can't do that either, and the last think I can not evolve during the fight and my computer opponents can.

Can you tell me what the button combination are for that please, because I have the Spanish version of the game and I don't understand it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing/holding R3(PS) or 2(Wii).  I found these sources but I have no way to test them.

[Fusion](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/939644-dragon-ball-z-budokai-tenkaichi-3/answers?qid=27118)

[Transformation](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_transform_in_dragonball_z_budokai_tenkaichi_3)

Comment: thanks i voted up your answer i m in work but when i test it at home i will accept it too

Answer (score -1):

This probably isn't much help, but,

- You can only turn into a great ape when the moon is out.
- Only Sains can turn into great apes.